# Mapping optional fields with JDBI ResultSetMapper

Tags: java, orm, mapping, jdbi

I have an Entity for which I have one EntityMapper that maps all attributes the entity has.

Then, in my DAO interface, I am fetching using @SqlQuery from the DB

- sometimes all Entity's attributes --> which is fine
- but sometimes I only fetch certain attributes --> and here the mapper fails with "SQLException Column xxx not found"

What is the recommended solution to this issue? I would like to have just one mapper per entity and really not fetch all the attrs all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private List<String> getFieldsPresentInResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        List<String> fieldsPresentInResultSet = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        for(int index =1; index <= metaData.getColumnCount(); index++) {
            fieldsPresentInResultSet.add(metaData.getColumnLabel(index));
        }
        return fieldsPresentInResultSet;
    }
```

Use this function to get all fields present in resultSet. Then you can check whether field is present in the result set or not. Something like,

```
  List<String> fields = getFieldsPresentInResultSet(rs);
  String field = fieldfields.contain("fieldName") ? rs.getString("fieldName") ? null ;
```

This way you can have single mapper per entity. You can check this [library](http://manikandan-k.github.io/jdbi_folder/) also.